# How does the Onusa weapon work?

Tags: the-wind-and-wilting-blossom

I was playing The Wind and Wilting Blossom, and I obtained an unusual weapon which I can't figure out. It's called the Onusa. Unfortunately, I sold the weapon out of frustration, and can't therefore provide screenshots.

The weapon was obtained in one of the story vignettes upon entering a new area. It looked like it might be cursed, but after picking it up, it shone radiant light and repulsed the darkness.

The targeting symbols on the weapon show green hexagons all around the player, and it says that it has "range 1" and "absorb 1 damage". I wasn't sure what that meant. I thought that maybe it would do a life leech effect, damaging all adjacent creatures and healing the user. I tried it in a battle, adjacent to an enemy, but all it did was damage the user. It did nothing to the enemy.

I realized that the hexagons on the targeting symbols for other weapons are usually red, so maybe the green hexagons meant that it targets allies. I decided that, maybe, it would heal adjacent allies and damage the user. I tried having a couple injured allies stand next to the user, and activated it. It damaged all of them.

I tried searching for information online, but found almost nothing. All I found were [these patch notes](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/686770/view/2198264290032070191), which simply say

> Reworked the Onusa Weapon to be a 1 range point blank AOE with 1 damage absorption

which is not helpful.

This weapon appears to have no function beyond damaging the user and their allies. Does it do anything beneficial at all? How am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 8):

I contacted the developers on their Discord, and figured out what the problem was.

They informed me that the weapon is intended to add a status effect to the user and adjacent allies that will absorb (negate) the next point of damage inflicted on them. I found this far from clear from the description, and was therefore not aware that I was imposing a status effect.

I was using the 2nd layout of the starting Leader, Mitsukuni. This layout includes a charm that adds 2 damage to any weapon that imposes a status effect on its target. So, the weapon was working as intended by applying this buff, but then immediately dealing 2 damage to everyone. One point was negated, and then the other went through. The result was that the weapon appeared to deal one point of damage to all allies.

The developer reproduced this behavior, and indicated that it may be a bug. Perhaps the charm will be updated to add damage only to negative status effects.